# Client results - SignalR - .Net 7

Tags: signalr, .net-7.0

I'm trying to use the new signalR client results feature that was first announced on .Net 7 preview 4 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-7-preview-4/ and recently released in .NET 7 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-asp-net-core-in-dotnet-7/.

Therefore, I'm upgrading an existing signalR application to .NET 7. But I didn't find examples on how to implement the feature. If you click the link from the .NET 7 release, it leads you to a confusing page with no information about the feature. The page from preview 4 has a small code snippet but when I try to use it, I get a IHubCallerClients does not contain a definition for 'Single' and no accessible extension method 'Single' accepting a first argument of type 'IHubCallerClients' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) error.

The server side of the application is currently using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR 1.1.0 package that, by the way, is marked as deprecated. I didn't find any clear information about an alternative to this package...

I made a simple hub to test the snippet from the preview 4 link, also using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR 1.1.0 and .Net 7, where I also get the error I mentioned.

```
public class HubTest : Hub
    {
        public async override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
        
        }

        public async override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
        
        }

        public async Task WaitForResult(string connectionId)
        {
            var randomValue = Random.Shared.Next(0, 10);
            var result = await Clients.Single(connectionId).InvokeAsync<int>(
                "GetResult", "Guess the value between 0 and 10.");
            if (result == randomValue)
            {
                await Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("EndResult", "You guessed correctly!");
            }
            else
            {
                await Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("EndResult", $"You guessed incorrectly, value was {randomValue}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong ? Should I be referencing another package ? Is there anything else I should do or set to be able to use the feature ?

I must confess I'm a bit loss due to the lack of documentation regarding the feature. I searched a lot for info about it, but didn't find anything really interesting. Do you guys have something in mind with examples about this topic ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-results
No package needed for SignalR on the server starting with 3.1.

Comment: David Fowler has a sample of using signalr client results in this repo: https://github.com/davidfowl/CommandAndControl

Comment: I linked to the docs for the feature, did you look at it? Here it is again https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-results If it's poorly documented you should file a github issue with specifics.

Comment: Yes, you shared the link from the .Net 7 announcing page I mentioned in the issue. I was able to find a small snippet there, very similar to the one from the preview 4 page. But i was not able to use that code. I'm not able to use the InvokeAsync method. My code only return SendAsync and SendCoreAsync as possible options. My Hub is on a .Net7 class library project. Please, do you know anything i could be possibly missing or making it in a wrong way ? Thank you.

Comment: The snippet in the doc shows `Clients.Client(connectionId).InvokeAsync<int>()`, have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

We renamed Single back to Client. The [documentation has been updated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-results) to reflect this.